# SharePoint hosted app, any user should be able to install

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-on-prem

I've created a SharePoint-hosted app, and I want not only Site collection admins to be able to install the app, but also members etc (not visitors).

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the permissions requested by app should not be those which are with admin only. For example, you can't ask for Full Control permissions in app manifest and expect a user with contributor access to install that app as the user himself doesn't have that permission.

Comment: Thanks. But if I use scope: search in my app it's not possible? Because even if I hade Read on every scope, except Search (QueryAsUserIgnoreApp...) the member cannot install the app.

Comment: @RangeRover, not sure about this but `Read` is perhaps too low a permission in case of search.

Comment: Search uses QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipals, not read.

Comment: @RangeRover, sorry, I am not really sure of that part and unfortunately I don't have app environment setup to test it right now.

Comment: Ok, you answered my first question anyways, thanks :)

Comment: If you require QueryAsUserIgnorAppPrincipals permission then only Site Administrators can install the app. Non-Admin users cannot grant permissions to retrieve results from other site collections which is what this permission does.